# removing process (and child process) access to file systems?

Tags: security, permissions, cgi

is there a unix-type free OS that allows me to remove all disk access for a specific process and any of its children?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use Perl6::Slurp;

my $infile= slurp("/etc/myprogramconfit.txt");  ## still legal

**remove_all_disk_access();**

## STDIN and STDOUT don't access disk, so they are still ok.
while (<>) {
   print "$_";
   ## somewhere deep inside another module...

   open(FO, "< /etc/password");  ### ALWAYS ERROR: $!
   open(FO, "> ~/bin/ls");  ### ALWAYS ERROR: $!
   system("/bin/ls"); ## ALWAYS ERROR: $!

   ## even if the rest of my (cgi) program is exceedingly stupid,
   ## it will now be exceedingly hard to break into my system.
   ## better than chroot?!  no setuid involved anywhere.
}
```

(background---I would like to talk to this process only via STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR.  it will be a CGI process that will receive arbitrary input from the general public, which I do not trust fully.  if I can remove all file system access, esp dynamically after the process has read a few configuration files and just before it starts reading user STDIN, it would be heaven.  better than a sandbox or vm *FOR MY NEEDS*.   almost unbreakable in some respects.  minimal maintenance needs.  I am not suggesting that this would work for everyone and solve all problems, but this would, with minimum maintenance and attention requirements, solve a huge headache for *me*.  Security is a hard problem right now, even when it does not have to be.  *Convenience* would go a long way towards enabling security for non-pros.)

advice appreciated.

/iaw

Comment: There are many ways to do this sort of thing: chroot, SELinux, containers, etc. What have you already looked at?

Comment: all of the above.  none are halfway easy to deploy...and worse, in many cases, accidental misconfiguration can make things worse because they often require su privs to set up.   if there was a system call like this, it would be trivially easy for me to deploy.  I think linux does not have it.  *bsd?  anything else?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like SELinux would suit your needs.  I'm not familiar enough with it to create the configuration you would need however.  SELinux is available on several Linux distros.

Many daemons require root privileges to get started (say, to listen on port 80) but drop those privileges as soon as they can and run after that as an unprivileged user.  This technique could allow you to read in config files and then have the long-running daemon be unable to read those same config files.  A different approach would be to pass the config files in over STDIN as the process starts.

A chroot may also suit your needs if you set appropriate file permissions inside the chroot such that the process cannot read or write anything.

Both of these options do involve some extra work but they're not all that inconvenient.

Comment: read up for quite a while on this.  I am pretty sure that neither of them does this.